# How do I sync state from the DOM to my React Component in an Isomorphic Application?

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

### My Problem

I am building an Isomorphic Application in [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) which first renders a component server-side, then takes advantage of React's intelligent re-rendering browser-side.

I have run into a situation where the DOM can become out of sync with the React component's state before React is able to first render browser-side. This can happen when the user is on a slow internet connection, and the `react.js` file takes a while to download *(which is also the reason I'm building an Isomorphic Application)*

### Example

Here is an example I put together to show this happening: [http://jsfiddle.net/jesstelford/z4o44esb](http://jsfiddle.net/jesstelford/z4o44esb/)

- Run this example
- Togle the checkbox
- Click "Render React"
- The current React state is output in the console
- Note that it is still set to { done: false } which is incorrect

```js
var TodoItem = React.createClass({

  // ...

  render: function() {
    return (
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.state.done} onChange={this.onChange} />
        {this.props.name}
      </label>
    );
  }
});

// User toggles checkbox ON here, before React is rendered browser-side

// render using React browser-side
var renderedComponent = React.render(component, document.getElementById('content'));

// Incorrectly outputs { done: false }  
console.log('React state:', renderedComponent.state);
```

### Possible *(Half)* Solution

I have found one possible solution using [`React refs`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html): [http://jsfiddle.net/jesstelford/z4o44esb/2](http://jsfiddle.net/jesstelford/z4o44esb/2/)

```js
var TodoItem = React.createClass({

  // ...

  syncStateFromDOM: function() {
    this.setDone(this.refs.done.getDOMNode().checked);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <label>
        <input ref="done" type="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.state.done} onChange={this.onChange} />
        {this.props.name}
      </label>
    );
  }
});

// User toggles checkbox ON here, before React is rendered browser-side

// render using React browser-side
var renderedComponent = React.render(component, document.getElementById('content'));

// Sync state from the DOM
renderedComponent.syncStateFromDOM()

// Correctly outputs { done: true }  
console.log('React state:', renderedComponent.state);
```

The downsides to this approach are:

- the state is synced **after** the DOM is rendered
- Requires extra code external to the component itself to sync on first render

### My Question

When pre-rendering a React Component server-side, is there any way to sync DOM state to that React Component before it has rendered browser-side, given the DOM has been manipulated by the user before React is loaded browser-side?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "the user changed the state server-side"?

Comment: I didn't say that anywhere in the question - is there another phrase that I can clarify for you?

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you defer rendering React longer than document#ready. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an intriguing question! At a high level, the problem is that React isn't catching the 'change' event that bubbled up to the top-level component when you clicked the checkbox, because it wasn't instantiated yet on the client side. Your half-solution handles this by manually simulating a call to `onChange`. I started thinking that you might need to queue onChange events... but then I realized that React already has everything you need.

The "three-quarters" solution is to simply rename `syncStateFromDOM` to [`componentDidMount`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount), and don't even bother calling it manually. As per the docs, in the most recent versions of React, `componentDidMount` is only called in the browser, and it's a lifecycle callback for after the component mounts (i.e. when `React.render` is about to return). It's the perfect place for your use case. See: http://jsfiddle.net/qdt4z3w9/

That solves your problem of code external to the component itself! But there's still state-setting going on after the original render takes place. Unfortunately, I think this is fundamentally the way React works - in order to be able to match up existing DOM nodes to refs, each component needs to be fully mounted first. But an extra Virtual DOM diff is a small price to pay, since it's designed to be lightning-quick.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's a great three-quarters solution! It looks like the 100% solution would be a lifecycle event somewhere between `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount`. For now, I'll leave it as unaccepted in case another solution comes forward that gets us closer to the 100%. Thanks!

Comment: Accepted http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6524881  - thanks @Hummlas!